# I'm messing around with the turtle import in python 2.7 with loops and the turtle won't move

Tags: python, python-2.7, turtle-graphics

I'm messing around with the turtle import in python 2.7 with loops and I just see the screen flash and the program exits.
Here is my code:

```
import turtle

colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
dColors = dict(enumerate(colors))


def circleOfShapes(aTurtle):
    edges = 3
    radius = 100
    for i in range(5):
        for k in range(360 / 5):
            aTurtle.color(dColors.get(i))
            aTurtle.circle(radius, None, edges)
            aTurtle.right(5)
        edges += 1
        radius -= 10


turt = turtle.Turtle()
turt.shape("arrow")

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("white")
window.exitonclick()

circleOfShapes(turt)
```

This is just me trying to make something cool for my kid and get him interested in programming at an early age like I wish I would have. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can put `turtle.done()` at the end to make the script wait.

Comment: I actually fixed the problem of the screen flashing. I tried to edit the title but for some reason it will not change.

Comment: Now, the turtle is just in the middle of the screen and wont move.

Comment: Ok, you don't _need_ `turtle.done()`, you could put move `window.exitonclick()` to the end of the script.

Comment: that did it. Thanks for the help

Comment: would you like to put it as an answer so I can check off on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly modified version of your code that runs on both Python 2 and Python 3.

```
import turtle

colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
dColors = dict(enumerate(colors))

def circleOfShapes(aTurtle):
    edges = 3
    radius = 100
    for i in range(5):
        for k in range(360 // 5):
            aTurtle.color(dColors.get(i))
            aTurtle.circle(radius, None, edges)
            aTurtle.right(5)
        edges += 1
        radius -= 10

turt = turtle.Turtle()
turt.shape("arrow")
#turt.hideturtle()
#turt.speed(0)

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor("white")

circleOfShapes(turt)
window.exitonclick()
```

You can speed things up by un-commenting either or both of `#turt.hideturtle()` `#turt.speed(0)`

---

I changed the division in your inner `range` call to `360 // 5` to ensure that it returns an integer. That makes the code more compatible with Python 2 and Python 3.

In Python 2 the `/` division operator will return an `int` if its operands are both `int`s, in Python 3 it will always return a `float`. So when you want an `int` quotient it's alwys best to use the `//` floor division operator.

The Python 2 `range` will accept a `float` arg, but it will give a deprecation warning. In Python 3 , it will just raise an error.

Answer (score 1):

For me the code runs fine. The only problem is in your for loop you are trying to loop with a float in line 11. You need to use an integer. You could int cast it. That should fix it. Hope this helps.

EDIT: Another problem with the code is the
    window.exitonclick()

Remove this or comment it out

Comment: This answer in its current conversational style would work best as a comment.

Comment: I did that but my turtle still just sits there. Weird that it works on your end...

Comment: In Python 2 it works because 360 / 5 evaluates to an int in Python 2 (unless you do from `__future__ import division` at the top of the script).